# C++ using signal slots for QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, moc

I have a small class that is not working properly, and I can't get what is wrong with it. The compiler gives the message:

```
main.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'CDetails::CDetails()'
```

This is the snapshot from the code:

```
//main.cpp
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>

class CDetails : public QObject
{   Q_OBJECT
    public:
        CDetails() {}
        ~CDetails(void) {}


    public slots:
        void cppSlot(const QString &msg)
        {    qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/testqml/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    CDetails *test = new CDetails();
    QObject::connect((QObject*)viewer.rootObject(),
                 SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),test,
                 SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));
    return app.exec();
}
```

And in main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    id: guide
    width: 360
    height: 360
    signal qmlSignal(string msg)
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    property double scaleFactor: 1.0
    property string iconUrl: "image.png"
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            guide.qmlSignal("Hello from QML")
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Thanks for the suggestion on constructor. Now the error is:

```
error: undefined reference to 'vtable for CDetails'
```

What is missed here? All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I do not understand how the selected answer fixes the "error: undefined reference to 'vtable for CDetails'" issue. I wonder if I am missing something?

Comment: @LaszloPapp - I followed the suggestion from PavelStrakhov: "You should place the class to separate header and source files". That worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing implementations of your constructor and destructor. Quick fix:

```
class CDetails : public QObject
{   Q_OBJECT
public:
  CDetails() {}
  ~CDetails(void) {}
   ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed that. check update. now it gives another error.

Comment: Q_OBJECT must be in a header file. You should place the class to separate header and source files.

Answer (score 6):

> error: undefined reference to 'vtable for CDetails'
>
> What is missed here? All suggestions are welcome.

Seems you are missing the moc include before the main function.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>

class CDetails : public QObject
{   Q_OBJECT
    public:
        CDetails() {}
        ~CDetails(void) {}


    public slots:
        void cppSlot(const QString &msg)
        {    qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;
        }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/testqml/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    CDetails *test = new CDetails();
    QObject::connect((QObject*)viewer.rootObject(),
                 SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),test,
                 SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));
    return app.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
...
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT += quick
SOURCES += main.cpp
...
```

Note that, you will also need to add your custom lines that were there before, like dealing with the application viewer, et al.

Alternatively, you could also decouple the class and the main.cpp which means you would put the declaration of the class into a separate header, and then the defintition into a separate source file.

The main.cpp would include the freshly established header, and you would need to make sure that the new header and source file are added to the `HEADERS` an `SOURCES` variables in the qmake project file, respectively to get through the moc processing.

Comment: Actually you can put all declarations and implementations of methods in a header file. But the class declaration has to be in a header, not in main.cpp.

Comment: @Pavel: that is not true. I have written several main.cpp only projects with simple Q_OBJECT classes into the main.cpp. The key is including the generated moc file.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - I guess the comment from PavelStrakhov makes some sense. I tried including main.moc, and it gives error: "no such file or directory". Without main.moc, the code works, but also had to add qtquick2applicationviewer.pri as suggested by TanyaKadam. But thanks for all the inputs and comments.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - just did that. took the suggestion, rebuilt and re-run it with qmake. The error about main.moc now appears as: {No rule to make target `main.moc', needed by `main.o'.  Stop}. But if I take out the main.moc then it runs nicely, at least for embedded.

Comment: I went to: Projects > Run > Deploy configurations > Details. Then selected: Verbose ouput. Then run the project without main.moc, and just work fine. Then tried to run again with main.moc. The only error ouput is that: {No rule to make target `main.moc', needed by `main.o'.  Stop.}. Whatever reason, at least without the main.moc it works, and the software debug, install and run behaving as expected.

Comment: Judith: please run the (n)mak VERBOSE=1 command from command line or set up the build settings in QtCreator and paste the output from its message output. Also, try to click on execute qmake in the popup menu, just in case...

Comment: @Judith: have you run it?

Comment: @LaszloPapp - Yes. I have run it and it works, no broken setups. Thanks for all feedback.

Comment: Just to add my 50ct: Though this is a workaround, it is not very pretty. Including .cpp files is (almost) never necessary and should always be discouraged. I'd consider the correct solution to put CDetails in a seperate header file, MOC that and then compile/link the resulting cpp file into the executable.
You already have .pro file, so those instructions can easily go there...